# Creating a local server visible through firewalls

Tags: windows, sockets, firewall

I have a local server written in C++ listening to inbound TCP connects using plain socket ::accept() and UDP recvfrom(). I have two problems with this that I wish to solve:

- Can I programatically make Windows let me open the accept socket without it automatically being blocked by the Windows (software) firewall?
- Are there any ports I can use that will allow my packets to pass through both Windows firewall and external firewall? Port 80 is often taken by things like [Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/home), but are there others? Will most external firewalls typically by default allow incoming UDP and TCP connects on port 80?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to look at something more conducive to desktop environments such NAT traversal techniques as [libjingle](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/index.html), [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Traversal_Utilities_for_NAT), or an overlay network such as XMPP.

Answer (score 1):

In general, network routers need Port Forwardng enabled for the listening port, and firewalls need the listening port opened.  If you are using a uPNP-enabled firewall/router, then you can dynamically set up those settings programmmably via the uPNP API.  But more times than not, uPNP is either disabled or unavailable, requiring manual settings by the firewll/router admin.