# Communicate to public IP from a local network (WinSock, C)

Tags: c, windows, sockets, lan

I'm new to this forum (at least at asking questions), so please be patient. I'm trying to write simple client-server applications to communicate using datagram (UDP) sockets, with C and Windows.

The scenario is very simple, I want to be able to send/receive data from a machine in some local network (behind a GATEWAY/NAT) to some host having public IP. I can send the data, but it seems impossible to receive any data back, because the remote server can't see the client's local IP.

I don't want the user to perform manual port forwarding on the GATEWAY, and I also don't want to use UPnP because of security issues (though it also should be enabled by the user).

I think it is possible because applications like Skype or Browsers can do it, but how ?
Are there some automatically forwarded ports or things like that ? I'm exhausted of searching the web ... PLEASE HELP !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a local server visible through firewalls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590903/creating-a-local-server-visible-through-firewalls)

Comment: Indeed, the question is similar, but no answer. I don't want the user to perform port forwarding or enabling UPnP manually.

Comment: I was hinting towards my answer, STUN is the mechanism to get your public IP address, libjingle is a convenient way to implement hole punching without port forwarding, UPnP, or NAT-PMP.

Comment: It seem very similar to caf's explanation. I didn't notice that, sorry and thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For UDP connections, most home NAT gateways will automatically create a temporary reverse mapping for each outbound packet.

Consider a scenario where your client is running on the internal machine with IP address `192.168.4.5`, sending a UDP packet from port `65000` to the external address `64.34.119.12:6789`, via a gateway with external IP address `192.0.43.10`.  When the gateway sees your internal client send a UDP packet from `192.168.4.5:65000` to the external address, it will NAT it to an external address and port, like `192.0.43.10:5500`.  Your server will see a packet with a source address of `192.0.43.10:5500` and destination address `64.34.119.12:6789`.  The router also sets up a reverse mapping, so that if it sees a packet arrive on the external interface with a source of `64.34.119.12:6789` and a destination of `192.0.43.10:5500`, it will redirect it back to `192.168.4.5:65000`.  This mapping typically times out after a short while.

This means that in simple cases, all you need to do is:

1. On the client, use the same port to send to the server and listen for responses;
2. On the server, respond to the client at the address and port that the client's packet was receieved from, using the same server port that recieved the packet;
3. Have the client send the initial packet in the conversation;
4. Don't leave the "connection" idle for more than a few minutes at a time.

Comment: +1 on this answer. Also, depending on your local PC configuration, you may need to disable your local firewall software or configure it to allow this program to receive data.  Also, if your program is the "server" and sits behind the NAT, you may need to configure your NAT for port forwarding.

Comment: Thanks a lot, caf !!! I knew that this is some sort of black magic in the gateway.